# type ACC audio 1.28

Tags: vb.net, audio, ffmpeg, acc

want to know the version of the audio "libfaac 1.28"
is it called version 2 or 1 
is it called HE-ACC or HL-ACC
why called fACC 
it's exist with mp4 video

---

6C-69-62-66-61-61-63-20-31-2E-32-38

Answer (score 0):

**FAAC** doesn't support HE-AAC.

Use **Fraunhofer FDK AAC**:

[FDK AAC - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_FDK_AAC)

[FDK AAC - Official site](http://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/ff/amm/impl/fdkaaccodec.html)